# failing to index values using django-rest and elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

My DB is postgreSQL and I am using django_elasticsearch_dsl to connect django with elasticsearch.

for some reason when i run the command:

```
python manage.py search_index --rebuild
```

I recieve this error massage:

```
NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x058AEE38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the 
target machine actively refused it)
```

Its my first time using elasticsearch so I dont really know why I am recieving the error.

anyone has a clue how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the installation of elasticsearch all I was needed was to reinstall it on my pc